# How do I read from a pipe when not knowing how much data will be sent through the pipe?

Tags: c, shell, pipe, exec

I am trying to pass the output of an excev call through a pipe read it and then do another execv call on it. Example, ls -l | more. I am unsure how to read the data that is coming through the pipe. I have tried to find a good answer on how to do this with other resources but all are using very basic examples with a fixed size string. Do I need to make reading the data dynamically allowing for more or less or can it be a fixed sized buffer?

```
else {
    int pipefd[2];
    pipe(pipefd);

    int rc = fork();
    if(rc == -1) {
       error();
    }
    if (rc == 0) {

    // close reading end in the child
    close(pipefd[0]);

    // send stdout to the pipe
    if(dup2(pipefd[1], 1) == -1) {
            error();
    }

    // send stderr to the pipe
    if(dup2(pipefd[1], 2) == -1) {
            error();
    }

    // this descriptor is no longer needed
            close(pipefd[1]);

    // example 
    // path: /bin/ls
    // commands: ls -l
    if (access(path, X_OK) == 0) {
           execv(path, commands);
           error();
    }
           free(path);
           exit(1);
 }

} else {
    // parent process
    wait(NULL);
    // close the write end of the pipe in the parent
    close(pipefd[1]);
    // do I read here?


 }
```

Expected results are to read them from the pipe and then to do another execv call on that data.

Comment: your question is very broad, all depends on what you do with the read data, sometimes it is needed to memorize the read data sometimes not

Comment: `access(path, X_OK)` followed by `execv(path, commands)` is a [TOCTOU bug](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_of_check_to_time_of_use).  Just because `access()` doesn't return an error doesn't mean `execv()` will work.  `access()` isn't `execv()`, and it doesn't check everything necessary for an `execv()` to work, and even if it did, the things it checks can change. So you you aren't relieved from doing any error checking for `execv()` anyway. In general, checking if you can do something before trying to do it is **always** a bad idea and a bug. And the check **can be wrong**.

Answer (score 0):

You need to develop a protocol between the two ends of the pipe enabling you to send a "SET_BUFF_SIZE" message between the two ends of the pipe.
or
Use a fixed size buffer with start and end of message character strings which will enable you to "chunk" your data into multiple reads if needed.